# How to add many functions in ONE ng-change?

Tags: html, angularjs

How to add more than one function in ng-change?

Sample code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <select id="sel2" ng-model="updateUser.user.state" name="state"
        ng-change="change(); updateUser.user.city=''"
        data-role="listview" required>
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not have one function that calls all the others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add many functions in ONE ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813945/how-to-add-many-functions-in-one-ng-click)

Comment: But i am trying to reset City dropdown after change of States dropdown in the same form...

Comment: @MarcCliment I tried like ng-click format... but not working

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the following

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<select id="sel2" ng-model="updateUser.user.state" name="state"
    ng-change="change1(); change2(); updateUser.user.city=''"
    data-role="listview" required>
<option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a delegate function. Look through this post and it should get you started.

[ng-change on select option calling multiple unique functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629000/ng-change-on-select-option-calling-multiple-unique-functions)